Replace "_id" with "id" in array of nested documents
I have some Product documents that looks like this:
{
    _id: "some-id",
    name: "one",
    variations: [{
        _id: "some-other-id",
        some: "data"
    }]
}

What I want is to replace "_id" with "id" on variations when retrieving products with the aggregation pipeline but I can't figure this out. I can do it on the outer document, but not the array of nested documents. Here is what I have:
Product.aggregate([
    matchObj,
    {$addFields: {
        id: "$_id",
        "variations.id": "$variations._id"
    }},
    {$project: {
        _id: 0,
        "variations._id": 0
    }}
])

This almost works. The problem is that the 'variation.id' ends up as an array that contains a single item, the _id. How can I get this to just replace _id with id on the variations objects?

Have you considered just mapping over the variations array? If your arrays are as small as your sample documents then it's a fairly trival task. Something like this perhaps means you don't need your extra $project stage. You may also want to think about just doing an update to add an id field to the documents. With mongoose you can add it as a virtual instead.

Ya, I am doing that now. I was just hoping that there was a nice simple way to do it in the aggregate pipeline. The sample I gave is a simplified version, there will be more, but not much. Just hoping there was a simple way to do with $addFields.

If you wanted to use $addFields then you would need another stage like $unset to remove the _id key. Like this but obviously it has worse performance since it's using two stages.

"What I want is to replace "_id" with "id" on variations WHEN RETRIEVING PRODUCTS with the aggregation pipeline"

The provided answer by @ray satisfies your question and "replaces" the _id key with an id key in both the documents and variations array objects and does so in a single aggregation stage.

Every document in MongoDB must have an _id field. If it is not provided, it will be auto-generated(per official doc). Not sure why you want to drop/replace it, but you can do the followings in a single $set stage in an aggregation pipeline:

set the value of _id to be $$REMOVE. This will drop the _id field in the aggregation result
$map to iterate over the variations array and specify a project without _id

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      // your match here
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "_id": "$$REMOVE",
      "id": "$_id",
      "variations": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$variations",
          "as": "v",
          "in": {
            "id": "$$v._id",
            "some": "$$v.some"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

Nice and clean. Just needs the "id": "$_id", in the $set stage to replace the document _id like this for completeness.

As clearly stated, I am not trying to drop the _id field from the database. I am trying to replace it when RETRIEVING data so as to send id instead of _id to the front end. Please read the question before responding.

@jQueeny Thanks for the suggestion! Updated accordingly.

@LeeMorgan This is just an aggregation result, not really dropping the _id in the database(unless you put a $merge at the end of the pipeline.

I never said that I wanted to drop the _id in the database...
